# "creating default object from empty value" on update laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm new to Laravel and I'm getting this error message "creating default object from empty value". I'm supposed to update a current Facility but I'm not doing any good..Supposedly, when I click the SAVE button(edit_facilities.blade.php), it will update the data in the database but I think I'm doing it wrong..Can someone please help me on how to improve or correct my code..thanks.
This is my **CONTROLLER**:

```
      <?php
      namespace App\Http\Controllers;

      use Illuminate\Http\Request;

      use App\Http\Requests;

      use App\Facilities;

      use View;

      use Redirect;

      use Alert;

      use Validator;

      use Input;

      use App\Providers\SweetAlertServiceProvider;

      class FacilitiesController extends Controller
      {

      public $restful = true;


      public function update_facilities($id){

        $facility = Facilities::find($id);

        $facility->facility_name = Input::get('facility_name');
        $facility->category      = Input::get('category');
        $facility->save();


        Alert::success('Successfully Updated', 'Congratulations');
        return view('hotelier/facilities');
      }?>
```

And this is my VIEW for **view_facilities.blade.php**:

```
<h2>Hotel Facilities</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Facility Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="facility_list">
        @foreach($facilities as $facility)
            <tr id="facility{{$facility->id}}">
                <td>{{ $facility->facility_name }}</td>

                <td>{{ $facility->category }}</td>

                <td><a href="<?php echo 'edit_facilities/'.$facility->id ?>" value="{{$facility->id}}" class="btn btn-info open-modal">Edit</a>&nbsp;
                <a id="delete<?php echo $facility->id ?>" href="<?php echo 'delete_facilities/'.$facility->id ?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_fac(this)" value="<?php echo $facility->facility_name ?>">Delete</a>&nbsp;

            </tr>
        @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is for the VIEW of my **edit_facilities.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Edit Hotel Facility</h2>
<div class="col-md-4 form-horizontal">
    <form action="/update_facilities/'.$facility->id" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
        <label>Facility Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $facility['facility_name'] }}" name="facility_name" id="facility_name" autocomplete="off"></input>
        <br />
        <label>Category</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $facility['category'] }}" name="category" id="category" autocomplete="off"></input>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And my ROUTES:

```
Route::post('/update_facilities/{id}', 'FacilitiesController@update_facilities');
```

Comment: Code is right. What you want ?

Comment: @PrashantGPatil it seems right but I'm getting "ErrorException in FacilitiesController.php line 82:
Creating default object from empty value"..The line 82 is "$facility->facility_name = Input::get('facility_name');"

Comment: When you try to use a property on NULL value then this error appears. So you should always check if the $facility->facility_name is not NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change form tag and update_facilities function:

```
<form action="{{ action('FacilitiesController@update_facilities', $facility->id") }} method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

public function update_facilities($id){
    $facility = Facilities::find($id);
    if(count($facility) > 0){
        $facility->facility_name = Input::get('facility_name');
        $facility->category      = Input::get('category');
        $facility->save();
        Alert::success('Successfully Updated', 'Congratulations');
        return view('hotelier.facilities');
    } else {
        Alert::error('Facilities not found', 'Error');
        return view('hotelier.facilities');
    }
}
```

Comment: you saved my day...Thank you very much :) ..But on your form action you misplaced the "  instead of  `<form action="{{ action('FacilitiesController@update_facilities', $facility->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`..hehe...but it's only a small mistake..

Comment: Thanks for positive feedback :).